# Access service worker inside angular2/ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic2, service-worker

Currently the Ionic 2 [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/service-worker/) about service worker is very narrow and the access to the service worker is inside the index.html script tag.

**My question** - is it possible to access the service worker inside the app?

I tried `navigator.serviceWorker` inside my app component, but

```
Property 'serviceWorker' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know that navigator.serviceWorker actually exist, you can avoid this TypeScript compiler error by doing this

```
 (<any>navigator).serviceWorker
```

The point is that the error you see is just a TypeScript compile error and there are many ways to tell TypeScript that Navigator actually has a 'serviceWorker' property.